# How to prepend a line to a file inside a zip file

Tags: csv, command-line, zip

Is there an efficient command-line tool for prepending lines to a file inside a ZIP archive?

I have several large ZIP files containing CSV files missing their header, and I need to insert the header line. It's easy enough to write a script to extract them, prepend the header, and then re-compress, but the files are so large, it takes about 15 minutes to extract each one. Is there some tool that can edit the ZIP in-place without extracting?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fast answer, no.

A zip file contains 1 to N file entries inside and all of them works as un splitable units, meaning that if you want to do something on an entry, you need to process this entry completely (i.e. extracting).

The only fast operation you can do is adding a new file to your archive. It will create a new entry and append it to the file, but this is probably not what you need